# What is the vlc tag for?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just stumbled upon the [vlc](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vlc) and was wondering what for we have this:

- the excerpt as well as the text only describe what VLC is
- VLC is a specific software. So using that tag to me signalizes someone asks for exactly this software – which somehow doesn't fit the scope of our site

So either I missed something (and we should update excerpt as well as wiki of the tag), or the tag should be removed (and possibly retag affected questions).

Can you please enlighten me?

Comment: It's a surprisingly popular tag, with 16 questions (1 closed).  If they were all for VLC plugins, that would be useful, but I only see 1 of those.

Comment: That's exactly why I brought it up here: as it's currently used, I'd suggest to delete the tag as it makes no sense.

Answer (score 3):

The [vlc](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vlc) tag should work like any other software-specific tag ([thunderbird](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thunderbird), [drupal](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal), etc.):

For software that has to interact with VLC somehow. These would primarily (but not exclusively) be [VLC add-ons](https://addons.videolan.org/).

Of the questions currently tagged with it, only these should keep the tag:

- [VLC plugin to keep track how many times I watched a video](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/9916/vlc-plugin-to-keep-track-how-many-times-i-watched-a-video)
- [Plugin / Configuration for VLC able to show speed buttons](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/38904/plugin-configuration-for-vlc-able-to-show-speed-buttons)
- [VLC remote for Android with huge Play/Pause button](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/34376/vlc-remote-for-android-with-huge-play-pause-button)

For the tag description, I like the short style that we use for e.g. [drupal](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal), so something like:

> For software (add-ons etc.) that needs to work with the media player VLC.